# FireFox Extenstion - Using Components - Hex Decoding

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am working on a FireFox Extension and want to know what are these codes and what do they do :

```
    const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
        Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
            getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
        var windows = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
        global_win = windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        var my_integer = check_me_1() + check_me_2();
        alert(my_integer);

         function check_me_1() {
                try {
                    var _0x2cb6 = ["\x4E\x74\x74", "\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68", "\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E", "\x2E", "\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x0A", "\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65", "", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74", "\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65", "\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x37\x37\x30\x37\x33\x30\x39\x36\x20\x45\x45\x30\x45\x36\x31\x32\x43\x20\x39\x39\x30\x39\x35\x31\x42\x41\x20\x30\x37\x36\x44\x43\x34\x31\x39\x20\x37\x30\x36\x41\x46\x34\x38\x46\x20\x45\x39\x36\x33\x41\x35\x33\x35\x20\x39\x45\x36\x34\x39\x35\x41\x33\x20\x30\x45\x44\x42\x38\x38\x33\x32\x20\x37\x39\x44\x43\x42\x38\x41\x34\x20\x45\x30\x44\x35\x45\x39\x31\x45\x20\x39\x37\x44\x32\x44\x39\x38\x38\x20\x30\x39\x42\x36\x34\x43\x32\x42\x20\x37\x45\x42\x31\x37\x43\x42\x44\x20\x45\x37\x42\x38\x32\x44\x30\x37\x20\x39\x30\x42\x46\x31\x44\x39\x31\x20\x31\x44\x42\x37\x31\x30\x36\x34\x20\x36\x41\x42\x30\x32\x30\x46\x32\x20\x46\x33\x42\x39\x37\x31\x34\x38\x20\x38\x34\x42\x45\x34\x31\x44\x45\x20\x31\x41\x44\x41\x44\x34\x37\x44\x20\x36\x44\x44\x44\x45\x34\x45\x42\x20\x46\x34\x44\x34\x42\x35\x35\x31\x20\x38\x33\x44\x33\x38\x35\x43\x37\x20\x31\x33\x36\x43\x39\x38\x35\x36\x20\x36\x34\x36\x42\x41\x38\x43\x30\x20\x46\x44\x36\x32\x46\x39\x37\x41\x20\x38\x41\x36\x35\x43\x39\x45\x43\x20\x31\x34\x30\x31\x35\x43\x34\x46\x20\x36\x33\x30\x36\x36\x43\x44\x39\x20\x46\x41\x30\x46\x33\x44\x36\x33\x20\x38\x44\x30\x38\x30\x44\x46\x35\x20\x33\x42\x36\x45\x32\x30\x43\x38\x20\x34\x43\x36\x39\x31\x30\x35\x45\x20\x44\x35\x36\x30\x34\x31\x45\x34\x20\x41\x32\x36\x37\x37\x31\x37\x32\x20\x33\x43\x30\x33\x45\x34\x44\x31\x20\x34\x42\x30\x34\x44\x34\x34\x37\x20\x44\x32\x30\x44\x38\x35\x46\x44\x20\x41\x35\x30\x41\x42\x35\x36\x42\x20\x33\x35\x42\x35\x41\x38\x46\x41\x20\x34\x32\x42\x32\x39\x38\x36\x43\x20\x44\x42\x42\x42\x43\x39\x44\x36\x20\x41\x43\x42\x43\x46\x39\x34\x30\x20\x33\x32\x44\x38\x36\x43\x45\x33\x20\x34\x35\x44\x46\x35\x43\x37\x35\x20\x44\x43\x44\x36\x30\x44\x43\x46\x20\x41\x42\x44\x31\x33\x44\x35\x39\x20\x32\x36\x44\x39\x33\x30\x41\x43\x20\x35\x31\x44\x45\x30\x30\x33\x41\x20\x43\x38\x44\x37\x35\x31\x38\x30\x20\x42\x46\x44\x30\x36\x31\x31\x36\x20\x32\x31\x42\x34\x46\x34\x42\x35\x20\x35\x36\x42\x33\x43\x34\x32\x33\x20\x43\x46\x42\x41\x39\x35\x39\x39\x20\x42\x38\x42\x44\x41\x35\x30\x46\x20\x32\x38\x30\x32\x42\x38\x39\x45\x20\x35\x46\x30\x35\x38\x38\x30\x38\x20\x43\x36\x30\x43\x44\x39\x42\x32\x20\x42\x31\x30\x42\x45\x39\x32\x34\x20\x32\x46\x36\x46\x37\x43\x38\x37\x20\x35\x38\x36\x38\x34\x43\x31\x31\x20\x43\x31\x36\x31\x31\x44\x41\x42\x20\x42\x36\x36\x36\x32\x44\x33\x44\x20\x37\x36\x44\x43\x34\x31\x39\x30\x20\x30\x31\x44\x42\x37\x31\x30\x36\x20\x39\x38\x44\x32\x32\x30\x42\x43\x20\x45\x46\x44\x35\x31\x30\x32\x41\x20\x37\x31\x42\x31\x38\x35\x38\x39\x20\x30\x36\x42\x36\x42\x35\x31\x46\x20\x39\x46\x42\x46\x45\x34\x41\x35\x20\x45\x38\x42\x38\x44\x34\x33\x33\x20\x37\x38\x30\x37\x43\x39\x41\x32\x20\x30\x46\x30\x30\x46\x39\x33\x34\x20\x39\x36\x30\x39\x41\x38\x38\x45\x20\x45\x31\x30\x45\x39\x38\x31\x38\x20\x37\x46\x36\x41\x30\x44\x42\x42\x20\x30\x38\x36\x44\x33\x44\x32\x44\x20\x39\x31\x36\x34\x36\x43\x39\x37\x20\x45\x36\x36\x33\x35\x43\x30\x31\x20\x36\x42\x36\x42\x35\x31\x46\x34\x20\x31\x43\x36\x43\x36\x31\x36\x32\x20\x38\x35\x36\x35\x33\x30\x44\x38\x20\x46\x32\x36\x32\x30\x30\x34\x45\x20\x36\x43\x30\x36\x39\x35\x45\x44\x20\x31\x42\x30\x31\x41\x35\x37\x42\x20\x38\x32\x30\x38\x46\x34\x43\x31\x20\x46\x35\x30\x46\x43\x34\x35\x37\x20\x36\x35\x42\x30\x44\x39\x43\x36\x20\x31\x32\x42\x37\x45\x39\x35\x30\x20\x38\x42\x42\x45\x42\x38\x45\x41\x20\x46\x43\x42\x39\x38\x38\x37\x43\x20\x36\x32\x44\x44\x31\x44\x44\x46\x20\x31\x35\x44\x41\x32\x44\x34\x39\x20\x38\x43\x44\x33\x37\x43\x46\x33\x20\x46\x42\x44\x34\x34\x43\x36\x35\x20\x34\x44\x42\x32\x36\x31\x35\x38\x20\x33\x41\x42\x35\x35\x31\x43\x45\x20\x41\x33\x42\x43\x30\x30\x37\x34\x20\x44\x34\x42\x42\x33\x30\x45\x32\x20\x34\x41\x44\x46\x41\x35\x34\x31\x20\x33\x44\x44\x38\x39\x35\x44\x37\x20\x41\x34\x44\x31\x43\x34\x36\x44\x20\x44\x33\x44\x36\x46\x34\x46\x42\x20\x34\x33\x36\x39\x45\x39\x36\x41\x20\x33\x34\x36\x45\x44\x39\x46\x43\x20\x41\x44\x36\x37\x38\x38\x34\x36\x20\x44\x41\x36\x30\x42\x38\x44\x30\x20\x34\x34\x30\x34\x32\x44\x37\x33\x20\x33\x33\x30\x33\x31\x44\x45\x35\x20\x41\x41\x30\x41\x34\x43\x35\x46\x20\x44\x44\x30\x44\x37\x43\x43\x39\x20\x35\x30\x30\x35\x37\x31\x33\x43\x20\x32\x37\x30\x32\x34\x31\x41\x41\x20\x42\x45\x30\x42\x31\x30\x31\x30\x20\x43\x39\x30\x43\x32\x30\x38\x36\x20\x35\x37\x36\x38\x42\x35\x32\x35\x20\x32\x30\x36\x46\x38\x35\x42\x33\x20\x42\x39\x36\x36\x44\x34\x30\x39\x20\x43\x45\x36\x31\x45\x34\x39\x46\x20\x35\x45\x44\x45\x46\x39\x30\x45\x20\x32\x39\x44\x39\x43\x39\x39\x38\x20\x42\x30\x44\x30\x39\x38\x32\x32\x20\x43\x37\x44\x37\x41\x38\x42\x34\x20\x35\x39\x42\x33\x33\x44\x31\x37\x20\x32\x45\x42\x34\x30\x44\x38\x31\x20\x42\x37\x42\x44\x35\x43\x33\x42\x20\x43\x30\x42\x41\x36\x43\x41\x44\x20\x45\x44\x42\x38\x38\x33\x32\x30\x20\x39\x41\x42\x46\x42\x33\x42\x36\x20\x30\x33\x42\x36\x45\x32\x30\x43\x20\x37\x34\x42\x31\x44\x32\x39\x41\x20\x45\x41\x44\x35\x34\x37\x33\x39\x20\x39\x44\x44\x32\x37\x37\x41\x46\x20\x30\x34\x44\x42\x32\x36\x31\x35\x20\x37\x33\x44\x43\x31\x36\x38\x33\x20\x45\x33\x36\x33\x30\x42\x31\x32\x20\x39\x34\x36\x34\x33\x42\x38\x34\x20\x30\x44\x36\x44\x36\x41\x33\x45\x20\x37\x41\x36\x41\x35\x41\x41\x38\x20\x45\x34\x30\x45\x43\x46\x30\x42\x20\x39\x33\x30\x39\x46\x46\x39\x44\x20\x30\x41\x30\x30\x41\x45\x32\x37\x20\x37\x44\x30\x37\x39\x45\x42\x31\x20\x46\x30\x30\x46\x39\x33\x34\x34\x20\x38\x37\x30\x38\x41\x33\x44\x32\x20\x31\x45\x30\x31\x46\x32\x36\x38\x20\x36\x39\x30\x36\x43\x32\x46\x45\x20\x46\x37\x36\x32\x35\x37\x35\x44\x20\x38\x30\x36\x35\x36\x37\x43\x42\x20\x31\x39\x36\x43\x33\x36\x37\x31\x20\x36\x45\x36\x42\x30\x36\x45\x37\x20\x46\x45\x44\x34\x31\x42\x37\x36\x20\x38\x39\x44\x33\x32\x42\x45\x30\x20\x31\x30\x44\x41\x37\x41\x35\x41\x20\x36\x37\x44\x44\x34\x41\x43\x43\x20\x46\x39\x42\x39\x44\x46\x36\x46\x20\x38\x45\x42\x45\x45\x46\x46\x39\x20\x31\x37\x42\x37\x42\x45\x34\x33\x20\x36\x30\x42\x30\x38\x45\x44\x35\x20\x44\x36\x44\x36\x41\x33\x45\x38\x20\x41\x31\x44\x31\x39\x33\x37\x45\x20\x33\x38\x44\x38\x43\x32\x43\x34\x20\x34\x46\x44\x46\x46\x32\x35\x32\x20\x44\x31\x42\x42\x36\x37\x46\x31\x20\x41\x36\x42\x43\x35\x37\x36\x37\x20\x33\x46\x42\x35\x30\x36\x44\x44\x20\x34\x38\x42\x32\x33\x36\x34\x42\x20\x44\x38\x30\x44\x32\x42\x44\x41\x20\x41\x46\x30\x41\x31\x42\x34\x43\x20\x33\x36\x30\x33\x34\x41\x46\x36\x20\x34\x31\x30\x34\x37\x41\x36\x30\x20\x44\x46\x36\x30\x45\x46\x43\x33\x20\x41\x38\x36\x37\x44\x46\x35\x35\x20\x33\x31\x36\x45\x38\x45\x45\x46\x20\x34\x36\x36\x39\x42\x45\x37\x39\x20\x43\x42\x36\x31\x42\x33\x38\x43\x20\x42\x43\x36\x36\x38\x33\x31\x41\x20\x32\x35\x36\x46\x44\x32\x41\x30\x20\x35\x32\x36\x38\x45\x32\x33\x36\x20\x43\x43\x30\x43\x37\x37\x39\x35\x20\x42\x42\x30\x42\x34\x37\x30\x33\x20\x32\x32\x30\x32\x31\x36\x42\x39\x20\x35\x35\x30\x35\x32\x36\x32\x46\x20\x43\x35\x42\x41\x33\x42\x42\x45\x20\x42\x32\x42\x44\x30\x42\x32\x38\x20\x32\x42\x42\x34\x35\x41\x39\x32\x20\x35\x43\x42\x33\x36\x41\x30\x34\x20\x43\x32\x44\x37\x46\x46\x41\x37\x20\x42\x35\x44\x30\x43\x46\x33\x31\x20\x32\x43\x44\x39\x39\x45\x38\x42\x20\x35\x42\x44\x45\x41\x45\x31\x44\x20\x39\x42\x36\x34\x43\x32\x42\x30\x20\x45\x43\x36\x33\x46\x32\x32\x36\x20\x37\x35\x36\x41\x41\x33\x39\x43\x20\x30\x32\x36\x44\x39\x33\x30\x41\x20\x39\x43\x30\x39\x30\x36\x41\x39\x20\x45\x42\x30\x45\x33\x36\x33\x46\x20\x37\x32\x30\x37\x36\x37\x38\x35\x20\x30\x35\x30\x30\x35\x37\x31\x33\x20\x39\x35\x42\x46\x34\x41\x38\x32\x20\x45\x32\x42\x38\x37\x41\x31\x34\x20\x37\x42\x42\x31\x32\x42\x41\x45\x20\x30\x43\x42\x36\x31\x42\x33\x38\x20\x39\x32\x44\x32\x38\x45\x39\x42\x20\x45\x35\x44\x35\x42\x45\x30\x44\x20\x37\x43\x44\x43\x45\x46\x42\x37\x20\x30\x42\x44\x42\x44\x46\x32\x31\x20\x38\x36\x44\x33\x44\x32\x44\x34\x20\x46\x31\x44\x34\x45\x32\x34\x32\x20\x36\x38\x44\x44\x42\x33\x46\x38\x20\x31\x46\x44\x41\x38\x33\x36\x45\x20\x38\x31\x42\x45\x31\x36\x43\x44\x20\x46\x36\x42\x39\x32\x36\x35\x42\x20\x36\x46\x42\x30\x37\x37\x45\x31\x20\x31\x38\x42\x37\x34\x37\x37\x37\x20\x38\x38\x30\x38\x35\x41\x45\x36\x20\x46\x46\x30\x46\x36\x41\x37\x30\x20\x36\x36\x30\x36\x33\x42\x43\x41\x20\x31\x31\x30\x31\x30\x42\x35\x43\x20\x38\x46\x36\x35\x39\x45\x46\x46\x20\x46\x38\x36\x32\x41\x45\x36\x39\x20\x36\x31\x36\x42\x46\x46\x44\x33\x20\x31\x36\x36\x43\x43\x46\x34\x35\x20\x41\x30\x30\x41\x45\x32\x37\x38\x20\x44\x37\x30\x44\x44\x32\x45\x45\x20\x34\x45\x30\x34\x38\x33\x35\x34\x20\x33\x39\x30\x33\x42\x33\x43\x32\x20\x41\x37\x36\x37\x32\x36\x36\x31\x20\x44\x30\x36\x30\x31\x36\x46\x37\x20\x34\x39\x36\x39\x34\x37\x34\x44\x20\x33\x45\x36\x45\x37\x37\x44\x42\x20\x41\x45\x44\x31\x36\x41\x34\x41\x20\x44\x39\x44\x36\x35\x41\x44\x43\x20\x34\x30\x44\x46\x30\x42\x36\x36\x20\x33\x37\x44\x38\x33\x42\x46\x30\x20\x41\x39\x42\x43\x41\x45\x35\x33\x20\x44\x45\x42\x42\x39\x45\x43\x35\x20\x34\x37\x42\x32\x43\x46\x37\x46\x20\x33\x30\x42\x35\x46\x46\x45\x39\x20\x42\x44\x42\x44\x46\x32\x31\x43\x20\x43\x41\x42\x41\x43\x32\x38\x41\x20\x35\x33\x42\x33\x39\x33\x33\x30\x20\x32\x34\x42\x34\x41\x33\x41\x36\x20\x42\x41\x44\x30\x33\x36\x30\x35\x20\x43\x44\x44\x37\x30\x36\x39\x33\x20\x35\x34\x44\x45\x35\x37\x32\x39\x20\x32\x33\x44\x39\x36\x37\x42\x46\x20\x42\x33\x36\x36\x37\x41\x32\x45\x20\x43\x34\x36\x31\x34\x41\x42\x38\x20\x35\x44\x36\x38\x31\x42\x30\x32\x20\x32\x41\x36\x46\x32\x42\x39\x34\x20\x42\x34\x30\x42\x42\x45\x33\x37\x20\x43\x33\x30\x43\x38\x45\x41\x31\x20\x35\x41\x30\x35\x44\x46\x31\x42\x20\x32\x44\x30\x32\x45\x46\x38\x44", "\x30\x78", "\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72"];
                    str = _0x2cb6[0] + global_win[_0x2cb6[2]][_0x2cb6[1]] + _0x2cb6[3] + global_win[_0x2cb6[2]][_0x2cb6[4]];
                    str = str[_0x2cb6[6]](/\r\n/g, _0x2cb6[5]);
                    var utftext = _0x2cb6[7];
                    for (var n = 0; n < str[_0x2cb6[8]]; n++) {
                        var c = str[_0x2cb6[9]](n);
                        if (c < 128) {
                            utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]](c);
                        } else {
                            if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                                utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]]((c >> 6) | 192);
                                utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]]((c & 63) | 128);
                            } else {
                                utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]]((c >> 12) | 224);
                                utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]](((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                                utftext += String[_0x2cb6[10]]((c & 63) | 128);
                            };
                        };
                    };
                    str = utftext;
                    var table = _0x2cb6[11];
                    var crc = 0;
                    var x = 0;
                    var y = 0;
                    crc = crc ^ (-1);
                    for (var i = 0, iTop = str[_0x2cb6[8]]; i < iTop; i++) {
                        y = (crc ^ str[_0x2cb6[9]](i)) & 0xFF;
                        x = _0x2cb6[12] + table[_0x2cb6[13]](y * 9, 8);
                        crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ x;
                    };
                    global_variable = crc ^ (-1);
                    return parseInt(global_variable);
                } catch (exc) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            function check_me_2() {
                try {
                    var _0x3ed1 = ["", "\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73", "\x6E\x61\x76\x69\x67\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x6E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x0A", "\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65", "\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74", "\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65", "\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x37\x37\x30\x37\x33\x30\x39\x36\x20\x45\x45\x30\x45\x36\x31\x32\x43\x20\x39\x39\x30\x39\x35\x31\x42\x41\x20\x30\x37\x36\x44\x43\x34\x31\x39\x20\x37\x30\x36\x41\x46\x34\x38\x46\x20\x45\x39\x36\x33\x41\x35\x33\x35\x20\x39\x45\x36\x34\x39\x35\x41\x33\x20\x30\x45\x44\x42\x38\x38\x33\x32\x20\x37\x39\x44\x43\x42\x38\x41\x34\x20\x45\x30\x44\x35\x45\x39\x31\x45\x20\x39\x37\x44\x32\x44\x39\x38\x38\x20\x30\x39\x42\x36\x34\x43\x32\x42\x20\x37\x45\x42\x31\x37\x43\x42\x44\x20\x45\x37\x42\x38\x32\x44\x30\x37\x20\x39\x30\x42\x46\x31\x44\x39\x31\x20\x31\x44\x42\x37\x31\x30\x36\x34\x20\x36\x41\x42\x30\x32\x30\x46\x32\x20\x46\x33\x42\x39\x37\x31\x34\x38\x20\x38\x34\x42\x45\x34\x31\x44\x45\x20\x31\x41\x44\x41\x44\x34\x37\x44\x20\x36\x44\x44\x44\x45\x34\x45\x42\x20\x46\x34\x44\x34\x42\x35\x35\x31\x20\x38\x33\x44\x33\x38\x35\x43\x37\x20\x31\x33\x36\x43\x39\x38\x35\x36\x20\x36\x34\x36\x42\x41\x38\x43\x30\x20\x46\x44\x36\x32\x46\x39\x37\x41\x20\x38\x41\x36\x35\x43\x39\x45\x43\x20\x31\x34\x30\x31\x35\x43\x34\x46\x20\x36\x33\x30\x36\x36\x43\x44\x39\x20\x46\x41\x30\x46\x33\x44\x36\x33\x20\x38\x44\x30\x38\x30\x44\x46\x35\x20\x33\x42\x36\x45\x32\x30\x43\x38\x20\x34\x43\x36\x39\x31\x30\x35\x45\x20\x44\x35\x36\x30\x34\x31\x45\x34\x20\x41\x32\x36\x37\x37\x31\x37\x32\x20\x33\x43\x30\x33\x45\x34\x44\x31\x20\x34\x42\x30\x34\x44\x34\x34\x37\x20\x44\x32\x30\x44\x38\x35\x46\x44\x20\x41\x35\x30\x41\x42\x35\x36\x42\x20\x33\x35\x42\x35\x41\x38\x46\x41\x20\x34\x32\x42\x32\x39\x38\x36\x43\x20\x44\x42\x42\x42\x43\x39\x44\x36\x20\x41\x43\x42\x43\x46\x39\x34\x30\x20\x33\x32\x44\x38\x36\x43\x45\x33\x20\x34\x35\x44\x46\x35\x43\x37\x35\x20\x44\x43\x44\x36\x30\x44\x43\x46\x20\x41\x42\x44\x31\x33\x44\x35\x39\x20\x32\x36\x44\x39\x33\x30\x41\x43\x20\x35\x31\x44\x45\x30\x30\x33\x41\x20\x43\x38\x44\x37\x35\x31\x38\x30\x20\x42\x46\x44\x30\x36\x31\x31\x36\x20\x32\x31\x42\x34\x46\x34\x42\x35\x20\x35\x36\x42\x33\x43\x34\x32\x33\x20\x43\x46\x42\x41\x39\x35\x39\x39\x20\x42\x38\x42\x44\x41\x35\x30\x46\x20\x32\x38\x30\x32\x42\x38\x39\x45\x20\x35\x46\x30\x35\x38\x38\x30\x38\x20\x43\x36\x30\x43\x44\x39\x42\x32\x20\x42\x31\x30\x42\x45\x39\x32\x34\x20\x32\x46\x36\x46\x37\x43\x38\x37\x20\x35\x38\x36\x38\x34\x43\x31\x31\x20\x43\x31\x36\x31\x31\x44\x41\x42\x20\x42\x36\x36\x36\x32\x44\x33\x44\x20\x37\x36\x44\x43\x34\x31\x39\x30\x20\x30\x31\x44\x42\x37\x31\x30\x36\x20\x39\x38\x44\x32\x32\x30\x42\x43\x20\x45\x46\x44\x35\x31\x30\x32\x41\x20\x37\x31\x42\x31\x38\x35\x38\x39\x20\x30\x36\x42\x36\x42\x35\x31\x46\x20\x39\x46\x42\x46\x45\x34\x41\x35\x20\x45\x38\x42\x38\x44\x34\x33\x33\x20\x37\x38\x30\x37\x43\x39\x41\x32\x20\x30\x46\x30\x30\x46\x39\x33\x34\x20\x39\x36\x30\x39\x41\x38\x38\x45\x20\x45\x31\x30\x45\x39\x38\x31\x38\x20\x37\x46\x36\x41\x30\x44\x42\x42\x20\x30\x38\x36\x44\x33\x44\x32\x44\x20\x39\x31\x36\x34\x36\x43\x39\x37\x20\x45\x36\x36\x33\x35\x43\x30\x31\x20\x36\x42\x36\x42\x35\x31\x46\x34\x20\x31\x43\x36\x43\x36\x31\x36\x32\x20\x38\x35\x36\x35\x33\x30\x44\x38\x20\x46\x32\x36\x32\x30\x30\x34\x45\x20\x36\x43\x30\x36\x39\x35\x45\x44\x20\x31\x42\x30\x31\x41\x35\x37\x42\x20\x38\x32\x30\x38\x46\x34\x43\x31\x20\x46\x35\x30\x46\x43\x34\x35\x37\x20\x36\x35\x42\x30\x44\x39\x43\x36\x20\x31\x32\x42\x37\x45\x39\x35\x30\x20\x38\x42\x42\x45\x42\x38\x45\x41\x20\x46\x43\x42\x39\x38\x38\x37\x43\x20\x36\x32\x44\x44\x31\x44\x44\x46\x20\x31\x35\x44\x41\x32\x44\x34\x39\x20\x38\x43\x44\x33\x37\x43\x46\x33\x20\x46\x42\x44\x34\x34\x43\x36\x35\x20\x34\x44\x42\x32\x36\x31\x35\x38\x20\x33\x41\x42\x35\x35\x31\x43\x45\x20\x41\x33\x42\x43\x30\x30\x37\x34\x20\x44\x34\x42\x42\x33\x30\x45\x32\x20\x34\x41\x44\x46\x41\x35\x34\x31\x20\x33\x44\x44\x38\x39\x35\x44\x37\x20\x41\x34\x44\x31\x43\x34\x36\x44\x20\x44\x33\x44\x36\x46\x34\x46\x42\x20\x34\x33\x36\x39\x45\x39\x36\x41\x20\x33\x34\x36\x45\x44\x39\x46\x43\x20\x41\x44\x36\x37\x38\x38\x34\x36\x20\x44\x41\x36\x30\x42\x38\x44\x30\x20\x34\x34\x30\x34\x32\x44\x37\x33\x20\x33\x33\x30\x33\x31\x44\x45\x35\x20\x41\x41\x30\x41\x34\x43\x35\x46\x20\x44\x44\x30\x44\x37\x43\x43\x39\x20\x35\x30\x30\x35\x37\x31\x33\x43\x20\x32\x37\x30\x32\x34\x31\x41\x41\x20\x42\x45\x30\x42\x31\x30\x31\x30\x20\x43\x39\x30\x43\x32\x30\x38\x36\x20\x35\x37\x36\x38\x42\x35\x32\x35\x20\x32\x30\x36\x46\x38\x35\x42\x33\x20\x42\x39\x36\x36\x44\x34\x30\x39\x20\x43\x45\x36\x31\x45\x34\x39\x46\x20\x35\x45\x44\x45\x46\x39\x30\x45\x20\x32\x39\x44\x39\x43\x39\x39\x38\x20\x42\x30\x44\x30\x39\x38\x32\x32\x20\x43\x37\x44\x37\x41\x38\x42\x34\x20\x35\x39\x42\x33\x33\x44\x31\x37\x20\x32\x45\x42\x34\x30\x44\x38\x31\x20\x42\x37\x42\x44\x35\x43\x33\x42\x20\x43\x30\x42\x41\x36\x43\x41\x44\x20\x45\x44\x42\x38\x38\x33\x32\x30\x20\x39\x41\x42\x46\x42\x33\x42\x36\x20\x30\x33\x42\x36\x45\x32\x30\x43\x20\x37\x34\x42\x31\x44\x32\x39\x41\x20\x45\x41\x44\x35\x34\x37\x33\x39\x20\x39\x44\x44\x32\x37\x37\x41\x46\x20\x30\x34\x44\x42\x32\x36\x31\x35\x20\x37\x33\x44\x43\x31\x36\x38\x33\x20\x45\x33\x36\x33\x30\x42\x31\x32\x20\x39\x34\x36\x34\x33\x42\x38\x34\x20\x30\x44\x36\x44\x36\x41\x33\x45\x20\x37\x41\x36\x41\x35\x41\x41\x38\x20\x45\x34\x30\x45\x43\x46\x30\x42\x20\x39\x33\x30\x39\x46\x46\x39\x44\x20\x30\x41\x30\x30\x41\x45\x32\x37\x20\x37\x44\x30\x37\x39\x45\x42\x31\x20\x46\x30\x30\x46\x39\x33\x34\x34\x20\x38\x37\x30\x38\x41\x33\x44\x32\x20\x31\x45\x30\x31\x46\x32\x36\x38\x20\x36\x39\x30\x36\x43\x32\x46\x45\x20\x46\x37\x36\x32\x35\x37\x35\x44\x20\x38\x30\x36\x35\x36\x37\x43\x42\x20\x31\x39\x36\x43\x33\x36\x37\x31\x20\x36\x45\x36\x42\x30\x36\x45\x37\x20\x46\x45\x44\x34\x31\x42\x37\x36\x20\x38\x39\x44\x33\x32\x42\x45\x30\x20\x31\x30\x44\x41\x37\x41\x35\x41\x20\x36\x37\x44\x44\x34\x41\x43\x43\x20\x46\x39\x42\x39\x44\x46\x36\x46\x20\x38\x45\x42\x45\x45\x46\x46\x39\x20\x31\x37\x42\x37\x42\x45\x34\x33\x20\x36\x30\x42\x30\x38\x45\x44\x35\x20\x44\x36\x44\x36\x41\x33\x45\x38\x20\x41\x31\x44\x31\x39\x33\x37\x45\x20\x33\x38\x44\x38\x43\x32\x43\x34\x20\x34\x46\x44\x46\x46\x32\x35\x32\x20\x44\x31\x42\x42\x36\x37\x46\x31\x20\x41\x36\x42\x43\x35\x37\x36\x37\x20\x33\x46\x42\x35\x30\x36\x44\x44\x20\x34\x38\x42\x32\x33\x36\x34\x42\x20\x44\x38\x30\x44\x32\x42\x44\x41\x20\x41\x46\x30\x41\x31\x42\x34\x43\x20\x33\x36\x30\x33\x34\x41\x46\x36\x20\x34\x31\x30\x34\x37\x41\x36\x30\x20\x44\x46\x36\x30\x45\x46\x43\x33\x20\x41\x38\x36\x37\x44\x46\x35\x35\x20\x33\x31\x36\x45\x38\x45\x45\x46\x20\x34\x36\x36\x39\x42\x45\x37\x39\x20\x43\x42\x36\x31\x42\x33\x38\x43\x20\x42\x43\x36\x36\x38\x33\x31\x41\x20\x32\x35\x36\x46\x44\x32\x41\x30\x20\x35\x32\x36\x38\x45\x32\x33\x36\x20\x43\x43\x30\x43\x37\x37\x39\x35\x20\x42\x42\x30\x42\x34\x37\x30\x33\x20\x32\x32\x30\x32\x31\x36\x42\x39\x20\x35\x35\x30\x35\x32\x36\x32\x46\x20\x43\x35\x42\x41\x33\x42\x42\x45\x20\x42\x32\x42\x44\x30\x42\x32\x38\x20\x32\x42\x42\x34\x35\x41\x39\x32\x20\x35\x43\x42\x33\x36\x41\x30\x34\x20\x43\x32\x44\x37\x46\x46\x41\x37\x20\x42\x35\x44\x30\x43\x46\x33\x31\x20\x32\x43\x44\x39\x39\x45\x38\x42\x20\x35\x42\x44\x45\x41\x45\x31\x44\x20\x39\x42\x36\x34\x43\x32\x42\x30\x20\x45\x43\x36\x33\x46\x32\x32\x36\x20\x37\x35\x36\x41\x41\x33\x39\x43\x20\x30\x32\x36\x44\x39\x33\x30\x41\x20\x39\x43\x30\x39\x30\x36\x41\x39\x20\x45\x42\x30\x45\x33\x36\x33\x46\x20\x37\x32\x30\x37\x36\x37\x38\x35\x20\x30\x35\x30\x30\x35\x37\x31\x33\x20\x39\x35\x42\x46\x34\x41\x38\x32\x20\x45\x32\x42\x38\x37\x41\x31\x34\x20\x37\x42\x42\x31\x32\x42\x41\x45\x20\x30\x43\x42\x36\x31\x42\x33\x38\x20\x39\x32\x44\x32\x38\x45\x39\x42\x20\x45\x35\x44\x35\x42\x45\x30\x44\x20\x37\x43\x44\x43\x45\x46\x42\x37\x20\x30\x42\x44\x42\x44\x46\x32\x31\x20\x38\x36\x44\x33\x44\x32\x44\x34\x20\x46\x31\x44\x34\x45\x32\x34\x32\x20\x36\x38\x44\x44\x42\x33\x46\x38\x20\x31\x46\x44\x41\x38\x33\x36\x45\x20\x38\x31\x42\x45\x31\x36\x43\x44\x20\x46\x36\x42\x39\x32\x36\x35\x42\x20\x36\x46\x42\x30\x37\x37\x45\x31\x20\x31\x38\x42\x37\x34\x37\x37\x37\x20\x38\x38\x30\x38\x35\x41\x45\x36\x20\x46\x46\x30\x46\x36\x41\x37\x30\x20\x36\x36\x30\x36\x33\x42\x43\x41\x20\x31\x31\x30\x31\x30\x42\x35\x43\x20\x38\x46\x36\x35\x39\x45\x46\x46\x20\x46\x38\x36\x32\x41\x45\x36\x39\x20\x36\x31\x36\x42\x46\x46\x44\x33\x20\x31\x36\x36\x43\x43\x46\x34\x35\x20\x41\x30\x30\x41\x45\x32\x37\x38\x20\x44\x37\x30\x44\x44\x32\x45\x45\x20\x34\x45\x30\x34\x38\x33\x35\x34\x20\x33\x39\x30\x33\x42\x33\x43\x32\x20\x41\x37\x36\x37\x32\x36\x36\x31\x20\x44\x30\x36\x30\x31\x36\x46\x37\x20\x34\x39\x36\x39\x34\x37\x34\x44\x20\x33\x45\x36\x45\x37\x37\x44\x42\x20\x41\x45\x44\x31\x36\x41\x34\x41\x20\x44\x39\x44\x36\x35\x41\x44\x43\x20\x34\x30\x44\x46\x30\x42\x36\x36\x20\x33\x37\x44\x38\x33\x42\x46\x30\x20\x41\x39\x42\x43\x41\x45\x35\x33\x20\x44\x45\x42\x42\x39\x45\x43\x35\x20\x34\x37\x42\x32\x43\x46\x37\x46\x20\x33\x30\x42\x35\x46\x46\x45\x39\x20\x42\x44\x42\x44\x46\x32\x31\x43\x20\x43\x41\x42\x41\x43\x32\x38\x41\x20\x35\x33\x42\x33\x39\x33\x33\x30\x20\x32\x34\x42\x34\x41\x33\x41\x36\x20\x42\x41\x44\x30\x33\x36\x30\x35\x20\x43\x44\x44\x37\x30\x36\x39\x33\x20\x35\x34\x44\x45\x35\x37\x32\x39\x20\x32\x33\x44\x39\x36\x37\x42\x46\x20\x42\x33\x36\x36\x37\x41\x32\x45\x20\x43\x34\x36\x31\x34\x41\x42\x38\x20\x35\x44\x36\x38\x31\x42\x30\x32\x20\x32\x41\x36\x46\x32\x42\x39\x34\x20\x42\x34\x30\x42\x42\x45\x33\x37\x20\x43\x33\x30\x43\x38\x45\x41\x31\x20\x35\x41\x30\x35\x44\x46\x31\x42\x20\x32\x44\x30\x32\x45\x46\x38\x44", "\x30\x78", "\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72", "\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68", "\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E"];
                    str = function() {
                        var _0x7691x1 = _0x3ed1[0];
                        try {
                            var _0x7691x2 = global_win[_0x3ed1[2]][_0x3ed1[1]];
                            for (var i = 0; i < _0x7691x2[_0x3ed1[3]]; i++) {
                                _0x7691x1 += _0x7691x2[i][_0x3ed1[4]];
                            };
                        } catch (e) {};
                        return _0x7691x1;
                    }();
                    str = str[_0x3ed1[6]](/\r\n/g, _0x3ed1[5]);
                    var utftext = _0x3ed1[0];
                    for (var n = 0; n < str[_0x3ed1[3]]; n++) {
                        var c = str[_0x3ed1[7]](n);
                        if (c < 128) {
                            utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]](c);
                        } else {
                            if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                                utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]]((c >> 6) | 192);
                                utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]]((c & 63) | 128);
                            } else {
                                utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]]((c >> 12) | 224);
                                utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]](((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                                utftext += String[_0x3ed1[8]]((c & 63) | 128);
                            };
                        };
                    };
                    str = utftext;
                    var table = _0x3ed1[9];
                    var crc = 0;
                    var x = 0;
                    var y = 0;
                    crc = crc ^ (-1);
                    for (var i = 0, iTop = str[_0x3ed1[3]]; i < iTop; i++) {
                        y = (crc ^ str[_0x3ed1[7]](i)) & 0xFF;
                        x = _0x3ed1[10] + table[_0x3ed1[11]](y * 9, 8);
                        crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ x;
                    };
                    crc = crc ^ (-1);
                    var z = 0;
                    for (var zz = 0; global_win[_0x3ed1[13]][_0x3ed1[12]] >= (1 << zz); zz++) {
                        z += ((global_win[_0x3ed1[13]][_0x3ed1[12]] & (1 << zz)) ? 2 : 1);
                    };
                    global_variable = z * (crc & ((1 << 26) - 1));
                    return parseInt(global_variable);
                } catch (exc) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

I think check_me_1() and check_me_2() functions have been encoded, how can i decode them?

**EDIT**
there is a relation between check_me_1() and check_me_2() functions!
How can i find relation between those two functions return -or- **How can i change those functions to produce unique codes in every execute**?

Comment: This is some weird code. `global_variable` is not declared globally which is weird, but i do see it being set in the compressed code in the `check_me` functions in a way that makes it global. And `windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow` which is what `global_win` is set to, is one of the currently open XUL Windows. I didn't look at the arrays of `_0x2cb6` and `_0x3ed1` as its very long and ugly (compressed code) :P

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for the comment, you know : those two returns are produced (same in every run) and are sent to a remote server. remote server check them and return true or false value. if you send those returns 10 times to remote server, remote server returns false. i want to change those functions to produce unique codes in every run to prevent remote server to return false.

Comment: Oh man that sounds real yucky, but yeah it looks like those things need to be decoded before we can tell you what is really going on, @Raul got the deocding started buts it not enough for me to see whats going on :( boy is it annoying when people obfuscate open source code, i mean like what are they afraid of? and like why? its open source!? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need work :D
But for start you can do a console.log of _0x2cb6

This variable have a collection of names like

```
["Ntt", "width", "screen", ".", "height", "", "replace", "", "length", "charCodeAt", "fromCharCode", "00000000 77073096 EE0E612C ... 706AF48F , "0x", "substr"]
```

This name are using to access properties in objects.

I'm not sure that the author want that you do this work...